# static function as class template parameter - cause maintainability issue

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, maintainability

After I learned how to pass static function (`HashFunction`) as a class (`Collection<T,HashFunction>`) template parameter, I am very addicted to it.

I use it in many places ...  now I just realize that if I want to change `HashFunction`'s signature, I will be obliged to modify code in various location.

### Example

There are some classes (`B` and `C`) that are designed to be used as element of a custom collection (`Collection<T,HashFunction>`):-

```
class B{
    int bHash;
    public: static int& getHash(B& b){return b.bHash;}     //#1
    //.... other complex thing about B ....
};

class C{
    int cHash1;
    public: static int& getHash1(C& c){return c.cHash1;}   //#2
    int cHash2;
    public: static int& getHash2(C& c){return c.cHash2;}   //#3
    //.... other complex thing about C ....
};
//There are about 20 places, i.e. #1 to #20
//They have a thing in common : return an integer field
```

The `Collection<T,HashFunction>` (its code is not shown) works similar as a hashset of `T`.

Here is the usage:-

```
Collection<B,&B::getHash> collectB;
Collection<C,&C::getHash1> collectC1;
Collection<C,&C::getHash2> collectC2;
//There are about 30+ locations.
```

### Problem

Signature of the hash function (`#1`,`#2`,`#3` and inside `Collection`) may require change in the future.

For example, the signature may change from

```
int bHash;
static int& getHash(B& b){return b.bHash;}
```

to

```
HashStructure bHash; //"HashStructure" is a new class
static HashStructure& getHash(B& b,int notUsed){return b.bHash;} 
//They tend to still have a thing in common : return a "HashStructure" field

//Here is the maximum possible difference :-
HashStructure bHash[3];
static HashStructure& getHash(B& b,int index){return b.bHash[index];} 
//They are likely consistent for both B and C.
```

Changing `Collection` to use the new signature is not hard, but changing all signature of `#1` to `#20` is tedious.

This indicates a maintainability problem.

### Question

Suppose I can reverse time to when there are only `#1` to `#3`,
how to modify the code/design (in the example) to prevent maintainability problem.

**Opinions:**

- I should use inheritance (`A` and `B` derived from a new class),
  but it doesn't fit. (Because `B` can have unlimited amount of hash function.  Moreover, the names of hash function are likely different from `A`'s.)
- Some certain design pattern might help. (?)
- Variadic template and SFINAE might help. (from Danh's comment, thank!)

Comment: auto return type?

Comment: @Danh Thank .... partially solve, but type of field still have to be updated by hand

Comment: `typedef some_type hash_type`; change 1 place and work everywhere

Comment: @Danh Sorry, my example in the problem section is not good enough.  I have edited the function signature to be more different.

Comment: When you change number of parameters of a function, obviously, you must change all functions.

Comment: @Danh I think there might be some tricks ... some technique in a big picture (e.g. design pattern) ...  template trick ... or something cool like inheritance ...  people here often has very astounding idea.

Comment: It's able to make the function signature more robust (via variadic template and SFINAE), but the implementation will need to be changed, right?

Comment: @Danh Yes, the implementation will need to be changed, but in a somehow consistent way (roughly speaking, most complex is `[index]`, I have edited).   I don't know how far variadic template and SFINAE can go for this case.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the maintainability problem, I would not have used functions as template arguments in the first place. I would have gone for a `1 type == 1 hash function` design, similar to what the STL does to solve the same problem.

Whichever reason you have to stick the different hash functions into the same class can be solved using either inheritance or friendship.

This way, only the call sites have to be updated when the signature change. You could also provide both signatures until every call site has been updated, allowing you to update the code base step by step.

Example:

```
#include <utility>

class C {
  static int cHash1;
};
int C::cHash1 = 0;

struct C1 : public C {
  static int hash(C &value);
  static int hash(C &value,bool);
};

struct C2 : public C {
  static int hash(C &value);
  static int hash(C &value,bool);
};

template <class Value, class HashFunction>
struct Collection {
  using key_type = decltype(HashFunction::hash(std::declval<HashFunction&>()));
};

template <class Value, class HashFunction>
struct CollectionUpdated {
  using key_type = decltype(HashFunction::hash(std::declval<HashFunction&>(), std::declval<bool>()));
};

int main() {
  Collection<int, C1> c1;
  Collection<int, C2> c2;
  CollectionUpdated<int, C1> c1_up;
  CollectionUpdated<int, C2> c2_up;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `getHash` can be factorized into

```
template <typename T, int (T::*hash)>
int& getHash(T& t) { return t.*hash; }
```

Then usage is:

```
Collection<B, &getHash<B, &B::bHash>> collectB;
Collection<C, &getHash<C, &C::cHash1>> collectC1;
Collection<C, &getHash<C, &C::cHash2>> collectC2;
```

And later, you can change implementation of `getHash` once:

```
template <typename T, int (T::*hash)[3]>
static HashStructure& getHash(T& t, int index) { return (t.*hash)[index]; }
```

Comment: On Wandbow with Clang, got a `error: use of undeclared identifier 'bHash'; did you mean 'hash'?`.